# How can I record full test that contains several Selenoid sessions in one video?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, remotewebdriver, selenoid

I am using two instances of RemoteWebDriver in my test and running it under Selenoid. After doing this, video is not recording fully. Is it possible to record the full test when running multiple Selenoid sessions?

Comment: please include what you have already done to try to solve this problem. You may also want to include if it worked when you were only using one instance and the steps you took to include to instances. This info may help someone help you resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Selenoid is only recording per-session videos and this can not be changed for the moment.